# Custom update lookup for accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a mostly static table of devices like so:

```
class CreatePlatforms < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :platforms do |t|
      t.column :model, :string, :null => false
      t.column :name, :string, :null => false

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :platforms, :model, :unique => true

    Platform.create  :model => "iPhone1,1", :name => "Original iPhone"
    Platform.create  :model => "iPhone1,2", :name => "iPhone 3G"
    [...]
  end
end
```

And a table, devices, that references platforms. Now I would like to send the model to the server, and have the created device linked to the corresponding id of that model in the database, similar to `accepts_nested_attributes_for :platform`. However, that creates the record unless there is an id in the attributes.

Is there any way with `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, or something similar, to use a different attribute to look up existing records?

I could manually swap it out in the controller like the following, but that is quit messy and a last resort:

```
params[:device][:platform] = Platform.find_by_model params[:device][:platform_attributes][:model]
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not passing the platform_id in from the view instead of the model?  Normally, this is something you'd handle with a select box.

Comment: This isn't for a website. This interfaces with an iPhone app, which knows it's model. The alternative would require downloading the list of platforms and matching up the model client side.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution:

```
def autosave_associated_records_for_platform
  if new_platform = Platform.find_by_model(platform.model) then
    self.platform = new_platform
  else
    self.platform.name = "Unknown"
    self.platform.save!
  end
end
```